# Cuenta acumulativa en access

Tags: ms-access, contador

estoy creando una columna de apoyo en **Access** que cuente los valores de otra pero de forma acumulativa, les detallo:

La columna: ***cadena*** tiene valores que se repiten y quiero contarlos pero que sea de forma creciente mientras aparecen, en Excel es sencillo con un contar.si y anclas la celda inicial, pero como podría tener algo similar en **ACCESS**?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y gracias por el apoyo.!!!!!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.